# Why code is not showing the List in the spinner that call with API?

Tags: java, api, retrofit, spinner, android-arrayadapter

> There is an Array of String that passes from the API. What is the problem with the code?
> I am trying to pass that value into a spinner

```
     Call<List<ResponseSubject>> 
  subjectOption=ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().subjectOption();
        subjectOption.enqueue(new Callback<List<ResponseSubject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ResponseSubject>> call, Response<List<ResponseSubject>> response) {

                List<ResponseSubject> responseSubject=  response.body();
            if(responseSubject!=null && responseSubject.size()>0) {

                String[] sub = new String[responseSubject.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < responseSubject.size(); i++) {
                    sub[i]= Arrays.toString(responseSubject.get(i).getData());

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,sub);
                    spin_class.setAdapter(adapter);

                    spin_class.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                        }
                    });


                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ResponseSubject>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

> In the above code, it is checking if the value coming from API is null or not. After checking that data is passing in an array and that array data is assigned to the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should be outside the "for" loop:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,sub);
spin_class.setAdapter(adapter);

spin_class.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        
    }
});
```

The final code should look like this:

```
Call<List<ResponseSubject>> subjectOption = ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().subjectOption();
    subjectOption.enqueue(new Callback<List<ResponseSubject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ResponseSubject>> call, Response<List<ResponseSubject>> response) {

            List<ResponseSubject> responseSubject=  response.body();
        if(responseSubject!=null && responseSubject.size()>0) {

            String[] sub = new String[responseSubject.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < responseSubject.size(); i++) {
                sub[i]= Arrays.toString(responseSubject.get(i).getData());


            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,sub);
        spin_class.setAdapter(adapter);

        spin_class.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<ResponseSubject>> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```